# CSV file upload not working

Tags: php, html, csv

I am trying to import csv file to database table using php. The problem is uploaded file is not recognized as csv file in the receiving page. Here is my code:

My form:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action="new_campaign.php" class="add_campaign_form">
    <table class="add_campaign_table">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Campaign Name<label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" class="name" name="camp_name" value='' required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Notes<label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea id="notes" name="camp_note" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="250"                        placeholder="Campaign details" value='' required>
            </textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Upload CSV File<label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <input type="submit" class="submit"  alt="Submit" width="120" height="30"/> 

    <br><br>
</form>
```

new_campaign.php

```
if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES["file"]['error']==0){
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "error uploading the file";
        }
    else {
        echo "hooray!";
        }
}
else {
    echo "this is not a csv file";
    }
}
else{
    echo "no files";
}
```

It keeps throwing me : "this is not a csv file"
I am getting the other field values in the receiving page. Any help?

Comment: What does `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` say the file type is?

Comment: added this echo "file type: ".$_FILES["file"]["type"];

Now getting this: "file type: this is not a csv file"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your input is `name="csv_file"`

```
<input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv" />
```

So it should be

```
if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES["csv_file"]['error']==0){
if (($_FILES["csv_file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")) {
    if ($_FILES["csv_file"]["error"] > 0) {
...
```

not `$_FILES["file"]['error']`/`$_FILES["file"]["type"]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sean. Here is the working code:

```
if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES["csv_file"]['error']==0){

//echo "file type: ".$_FILES["csv_file"]["type"];
if (($_FILES["csv_file"]["type"] == "text/csv")) {
    if ($_FILES["text/csv"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "error uploading the file";
        }
    else {
        echo "hooray!";
        }
}
else {
    echo "this is not a csv file";
    }
}
else{
    echo "no files";
}
```